# ReportViewer doesn't show embedded images

Tags: .net, sql, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have installed SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 2. I have a web page with a reportviewer, the report has an embedded image. I can see the image from the report manager but i cannot see the same image in the reportviewer.

It is an embedded image, thus, the image is in the report as part of the WebResource the file with the extension .axd.
Im using report builder 2.0. I'm working with ASP.NET 4.0.
Does some one have any idea why the reportviewer control don't show embedded images
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you are not telling much about your report? is that an embedded image? where is the image?

check here: [Adding Images to a ReportViewer Report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251715%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following instruction to the `httpHandlers` section in the `web.config`:

```
<add
  verb="*"
  path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd"
  type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```